# Why can't I just run a single instance from a template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Using the **aws cli**, it works perfectly:

`aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateName=mytempname,Version=24`

Using the **aws sdk**:

```
var params = {
  LaunchTemplate: {
    LaunchTemplateName: 'mytempname',
    Version: '24'
  }
};

ec2.runInstances(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
})
```

I get lots of errors asking me to add more params such as `MaxCount`, `MinCount`, `region`, but these are already defined in the template.

```
{ MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'MaxCount' in params
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'MinCount' in params
{ ConfigError: Missing region in config
```

Should I fetch the launch template first to be able to build the correct `runInstances`? But in that case, why is it working properly using the cli?

Comment: I went through the official documentation and these params are not part of the launchTemplate, the aws cli has default options like MaxCount 1, MinCount 1, I assume it us your default region. I think that's why it worked. I would extend the `params` object with the required properties.

Comment: I haven't thought about the default values I defined during `aws configure`, indeed... I will then extend the params with these mandatory parameters. Thanks!